# How to highlight matching sub-strings inside a ListBox?

Tags: wpf, listbox

I have one TextBox and one listbox for searching a collection of data. While searching a text inside a Listbox if that matching string is found anywhere in the list it should show in Green color with Bold.

eg. I have string collection like 
"Dependency Property, Custom Property, Normal Property". If I type in the Search Text box "prop"  all the Three with "prop" (only the word Prop) should be in Bold and its color should be in green. Any idea how it can be done?.

Data inside listbox is represented using DataTemplate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've created a HighlightTextBehavior that you can attach to a TextBlock within your list item templates (you'll need to add a reference to System.Windows.Interactivity to your project). You bind the behavior to a property containing the text you want to highlight, and it does the rest.

At the moment, it only highlights the first instance of the string. It also assumes that there is no other formatting applied to the text.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace StringHighlight
{
    public class HighlightTextBehavior : Behavior<TextBlock>
    {
        public string HighlightedText
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(HighlightedTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(HighlightedTextProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for HighlightedText.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty HighlightedTextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("HighlightedText", typeof(string), typeof(HighlightTextBehavior), new UIPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, HandlePropertyChanged));

        private static void HandlePropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            (sender as HighlightTextBehavior).HandlePropertyChanged();
        }

        private void HandlePropertyChanged()
        {
            if (AssociatedObject == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var allText = GetCompleteText();

            AssociatedObject.Inlines.Clear();

            var indexOfHighlightString = allText.IndexOf(HighlightedText);

            if (indexOfHighlightString < 0)
            {
                AssociatedObject.Inlines.Add(allText);
            }
            else
            {
                AssociatedObject.Inlines.Add(allText.Substring(0, indexOfHighlightString));
                AssociatedObject.Inlines.Add(new Run() { 
                    Text = allText.Substring(indexOfHighlightString, HighlightedText.Length), 
                    Foreground = Brushes.Green,
                    FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold });
                AssociatedObject.Inlines.Add(allText.Substring(indexOfHighlightString + HighlightedText.Length));
            }
        }

        private string GetCompleteText()
        {
            var allText = AssociatedObject.Inlines.OfType<Run>().Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, run) => sb.Append(run.Text), sb => sb.ToString());
            return allText;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's an example of how you use it:

```
    <Window x:Class="StringHighlight.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
        xmlns:b="clr-namespace:StringHighlight"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <x:Array x:Key="MyStrings" Type="{x:Type sys:String}">
                <sys:String>This is my first string</sys:String>
                <sys:String>Another string</sys:String>
                <sys:String>A third string, equally imaginative</sys:String>
            </x:Array>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox x:Name="SearchText"/>

        <ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{StaticResource MyStrings}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding}">
                        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <b:HighlightTextBehavior HighlightedText="{Binding ElementName=SearchText, Path=Text}"/>
                        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Interesting. Thnx for the light .